# Excel Dynamic Arrays - creating multiple dynamic arrays based on another one

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2019

I'm trying out the new functionality of Office 365's Insider versions of Microsoft Excel, **dynamic arrays**, and was trying to make something I've been wanting to do for some time in a simple way.

In essence, I would like to know if it is possible to either use each one of a dynamic array's values as an input to create a matrix of dynamic arrays, or even just plain creating the matrix below (table 3)  altogether with just one array.

Table 1 and 2 below are structured tables.

**Table 1 - Clients:**

```
| Client | Client Name |
|--------|-------------|
| C001   | Client 1    |
| C002   | Client 2    |
| C003   | Client 3    |
```

**Table 2 - Documents:**

```
| Document | Doc Description | Related Client |
|----------|-----------------|----------------|
| D001     | Doc 1           | C002           |
| D002     | Doc 2           | C002           |
| D003     | Doc 3           | C001           |
| D004     | Doc 4           | C002           |
| D005     | Doc 5           | C001           |
```

**Table 3 - Intended dynamic table:**

```
| Dynamic Array of "Clients" | Client 1 (*1) | Client 2 | Client 3 |
|----------------------------|---------------|----------|----------|
| Dyn. Arrays of "Documents" | D003 (*2)     | D001     | N/A      |
|                            | D005          | D002     |          |
|                            |               | D004     |          |
```

In the table above (*1) would be a Dynamic Array created with something like:

```
=TRANSPOSE(Table1[Client])
```

And (*2) would be a Dynamic Array created with something like:

```
=FILTER(Table2[Document], Table2[Related Client]={Client}, "N/A"}
```

**The issue is** that I haven't been able to find how to create all the Dynamic Arrays of "Documents" in a way that *they automatically grow in number along with the "Clients" dynamic array"*.

I.e. I can use simple relative cell references for **{Client}**, but when the "Clients" dynamic array changes (increases) that won't dynamically adjust the scope of the Document dynamic arrays. I thought that using a dynamic array reference of suffice, but it doesn't work as well (**{Client}#**).

I also tried to do this in a structured table, but sadly dynamic arrays don't work in those.

Is this possible?

Edit: I'm looking for an answer using dynamic arrays to their extent, please.

Answer (score 1):

**Your issue can be solved by using a `Helper Column along side of Table 2`:**

[image]

**How it Works:**

- Enter this Formula in Cell `O40` and fill it 
  down.

  ```
  =INDEX(M$34:M$36,MATCH(N40,L$34:L$36,0))
  ```
- In Cell `M48` enter this Array (CSE) Formula, 
  finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and fill 
  across Table.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($M$40:$M$44, SMALL(IF((M$47=$O$40:$O$44), MATCH(ROW($O$40:$O$44), ROW($O$40:$O$44)), ""),ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")}
  ```

**N.B.**

- You may replace `Blank` with `Not Aval`. 
  text message in last part of an Array formula,
  `ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")`, and it should written 
  like, `ROWS($A$1:A1))),"Not Aval.")`.

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not the answer I'm looking for. You're using array formulas, not dynamic arrays of the most recent Excel engine versions (example: [link](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) ). The particular issue of my question is how to make the dynamic arrays also span dynamically in reference to a base dynamic array. Also, I believe your formulas do what I've already done in the question, using dynamic arrays.

Comment: @acseven,, Check this `IF((M$47=$O$40:$O$44)` in Array formula which filter/extracts multiple rows based on Criteria in Cell M, N & O 47 and to associate data I've created Helper column `O40:O44`. I'm using `2013` & `2016` the link shows FILTER for `Office 365` is like `Google Spreadsheet` or I can say `Advance Filter in Excel` or similar to `SUMPRODUCT` mechanism ,, write me what you is missing or you want to add on with my Answer !

Comment: Hi - again, this is unrelated to my question. I'm not looking for how to create array formulas such as those, I'm looking to know if there is a way to solve an issue specifically using with dynamic arrays. If you don't have the latest Office 365 (2019) insider's edition you don't have access to these functions.

Comment: @acseven,, I think that you are looking for Dynamic Named Range,, which automatically expands when gets new entry !!

Comment: No, that's a different thing as well. Cheers